# Redirect anything after / with rewrite map

Tags: redirect, iis

I have a requirement to create some redirects with URL Rewrite in IIS that will redirect anything after / to a particular URL.

As an example, I would like to redirect anything after `foo.com/theOLDpath` to `foo.com/theNEWpath`.  For instance all of the following should be caught by this rule

```
foo.com/theOLDpath
foo.com/theOLDpath/
foo.com/theOLDpath/default.aspx
foo.com/theOLDpath/index.html
foo.com/theOLDpath/123.htm
foo.com/theOLDpath/456.aspx
etc...
```

I could probably figure out how to do that as a single rule in IIS URL        Rewrite for `foo.com/theOLDpath` but what I would really like to do is leverage a rewrite map as I have several different paths (roughly 200) that I want to do the same thing for.

Ideally I would like to have a rewrite map that looks like this.

`<add key="/theOLDpath" value="/theNEWpath" />
<add key="/anotherOLDpath" value="/anotherNEWpath" />
<add key="/andanotherOLDpath" value="/andanotherNEWpath" />
etc...`

Is this even possible?  If so how would I go about creating that?  If not, what are your recommendations for such a request?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes I would like to use a rewrite map however rewrite maps are typically one to one (/theOLDpath to /theNewpath and /theOLDpath/123.htm to /theNEWpath/123.htm, etc.)  I want to be able to redirect anything beginning with /theOLDpath/ to /theNEWpath/ without creating a entry in the rewrite map for every possible request.

Comment: in my opinion, you **could not** achieve your requirement with rewrite map. rules that use rewrite maps for storing static mappings between originally requested URLs and rewritten or redirected URLs.if you want to do this you need to create rule for a differnt path. you could just redirect /theOLDpath to /theNewpath not  /theOLDpath/123.htm to /theNEWpath/123.htm.refer rewrite map documnet.[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module#creating-a-map-for-rewriting)